# How to exactly measure size & position of Swift nodes depending on iDevice

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, sprite-kit, resolution

I'm creating my first Swift + SpriteKit game, and I'm dealing with this headache of having to resize all my stuff depending on the iDevice.

I got a class that based on the device its running, returns the name of it.
Having that name, I created a dictionary that based on a device String name, returns the resolution of that given device.

And then I created 2 functions -> getSizeBasedOnDevice() and getPositionBasedOnDevice()

Since I coded my game for an iPhone 6S. I thought that it would be as easy as doing a simple math calculation to get all these sizes and positions, but it looks like it wasn't.

These are my functions:

```
func getSizeBasedOnDevice(width: CGFloat, height: CGFloat) -> CGSize {
    // iPhone 6s w: 375, h: 667

    let deviceName = UIDevice.currentDevice().modelName
    let iphoneNative = ScreenSize(width: 375, height: 667)
    let resolution = Resolutions[deviceName]

    let newWidth = (CGFloat(resolution!.getWidth()) * width ) / iphoneNative.getWidth()
    let newHeight = (CGFloat(resolution!.getHeight()) * height) / iphoneNative.getHeight()

    return CGSize(width: newWidth, height: newHeight)
}

func getPositionBasedOnDevice(x: CGFloat, y: CGFloat) -> CGPoint {

    let deviceName = UIDevice.currentDevice().modelName
    let iphoneNative = ScreenSize(width: 375, height: 667)
    let resolution = Resolutions[deviceName]

    let newX = (CGFloat(resolution!.getWidth()) * x) / iphoneNative.getWidth()
    let newY = (CGFloat(resolution!.getHeight()) * y) / iphoneNative.getHeight()

    return CGPoint(x: newX, y: newY)
}
```

My iPhoneNative height and width would be my iPhone 6S'.
So the calculation was kinda simple to me, but it wasn't.

So having these example values:

```
Asset's width = 100 pts
Current Device (iPhone 4S) width = 320 pts
Originally designed Device (iPhone 6S) width = 375 pts
```

The math would be:

> (320 * 100) / 375 = 85.33

So the asset that had a 100 points width on my iPhone 6S would have 85.33 width on an iPhone 4S.

First I thought this seemed to be fine, but looking at the results, I  see I was doing it wrong.

Can anyone give me a hint?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me stop you :)

I understand your difficulties, this is not the right way to build a game for different screen sizes.

You should build your game only thinking about the `Scene`.

Then open `GameViewController.swift` and look for this line

```
scene.scaleMode = .AspectFill
```

This line does allow you to define how a scene should be represented into a screen (and it's particularly important for dealing with different screen sizes).

You have 4 options

> - `.Fill`: Scale the `SKScene` to fill the entire `SKView`.
> - `.AspectFill`: Scale the `SKScene` to fill the `SKView` while preserving the scene's aspect ratio. Some cropping may occur if the
>     view has a different aspect ratio.
> - `.AspectFit`: Scale the `SKScene` to fit within the `SKView` while preserving the scene's aspect ratio. Some letterboxing may occur if
>     the view has a different aspect ratio.
> - `.ResizeFill`: Modify the `SKScene`'s actual size to exactly match the `SKView`.

Comment: Thanks for replying :) i tried that.. setting different scaleModes... i currently have .AspectFill, but tested almost all of them... and i keep seeing the same results.. do you know why may that occur?

Comment: @msqar: `.AspectFill` could cut some parts of your scene but will fill the screen. It's like watching a widescreen movie onto an old 3/4 TV where the side bars are cropped (or watching a 3/4 old Star Trek TV episode on a modern widescreen with zoom enabled: the top and and bottom bars are cropped). What kind of representation are you looking for? What is the problem you are trying to fix?

Comment: To start, the main menu for example, where i got a few buttons with certain animation, 3 buttons for COMPETITIVE, PRACTICE AND OPTIONS and then mini buttons for different things including facebook & twitter accounts. For you to picture what im seeing... i can see that everything remained the same size as my iPhone 6S but in a 4S resolution.. you can imagine how messed up everything is, i can't even see the small buttons beneath OPTIONS button due to my ad banner on bottom.

Comment: @msqar: I understand and `.AspectFill` sounds like the right choice. It should scale your scene on a bigger screen... Are you sure you really did set `.AspectFill`?

Comment: Thing is, i started coding for iPhone 6S and im trying to make it fit in a smaller screen, and not viceversa.. that was the problem. Maybe it wouldn't be a problem if it was the other way around. And yes, right now is using .AspectFill :(

Comment: @msqar: No it should not be a problem. On a smaller screen the game should just scale down.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/118478/discussion-between-appzyourlife-and-msqar).

Comment: Omg ... then what am I doing wrong ? :s the major issues are the SKSpriteNodes not getting reduced accordingly... could it be that im not creating them properly or because im setting the sprite.size ??? maybe is setting that size for every single resolution either way and not caring about the device?